# How do I create pandas DataFrame based off start and end signals from other DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So in essence how do I take A(entry signals) and B(exit signals) and make C(trade signals)

Note that A is the Entry signal, and that B is the exit signal.
So:

```
A    B    C
0    1    0 (no entry signal yet, so 0)
1    0    1 (got entry signal and haven't gotten exit signal yet, so 1)
0    0    1 (got entry signal and haven't gotten exit signal yet, so 1)
0    1    1 (got exit signal and currently in position, so change from 1 to 0)
0    0    0 (nothing, so stay at 0)
1    0    1 (got entry signal and haven't gotten exit signal yet, so 1)
0    1    1 (got exit signal and currently in position, so change from 1 to 0)
0    1    0 (got exit signal, but already at 0, so do nothing)
1    0    1 (got entry signal and haven't gotten exit signal yet, so 1)
0    0    1 (nothing, so stay at 0)
```

So basically, a 1 in A serves as a signal to turn C "On", and a 1 in B serves to turn C "off".  If C was already on (previous element of C was 1), then a 1 in A does nothing, as C is already on.  Similarly, if C is already off (previous element of C was 0), then a 1 in B does nothing, as C is already off.  Basically, A has a list of signals to enter a trade, and B has a list of signals of when to exit, but you can only enter if you're not in the trade, and you can only exit if you're in a trade, so C is the list of whether you are in the trade or not.

I tried implementing your solution, as follows:

```
def generate_signals(self):
      signals = pandas.DataFrame(index=self.data.index)
      signals['Date'] = self.data['Date']
      signals['Close'] = self.data['Close']
      signals['fast_MA'] = pandas.stats.moments.ewma(self.data['Close'],
                                                     span=self.short_window)
      signals['slow_MA'] = pandas.stats.moments.ewma(self.data['Close'],
                                                     span=self.long_window)
      signalinfo = pandas.DataFrame(index=signals.index)
      signalinfo['entry_signals'] = numpy.where(signals['fast_MA'] >
                                                signals['slow_MA'], 1.0, 0.0)
      signals['stop'] = (data['Open'].shift(-1)
                         [(signalinfo['entry_signals'] == 1.0)
                          & (signalinfo['entry_signals']
                             .shift(1) == 0.0)])
      signals['stop'] = signals['stop'].fillna(0.0)
      signals['stop'] = signals['stop'].apply(lambda x: .97 * x)
      signals['stop'] = (signals['stop']
                         .replace(to_replace=0.0, method='ffill'))
      signalinfo['exit_signals'] = numpy.where(signals['Close'] <=
                                               signals['stop'], 1.0, 0.0)

      #process entry and exit signals to form trade signals
      signalinfo['Close'] = self.data['Close']
      mask = signalinfo.copy().astype(bool)
      signalinfo.entry_signals[mask.entry_signals] = signalinfo.index
      signalinfo.exit_signals[mask.exit_signals] = signalinfo.index
      signalinfo = signalinfo[mask].ffill().fillna(0)
      signalinfo['signal'] = (signalinfo['exit_signals']
                              < signalinfo['entry_signals']).astype(int)
      signalinfo['entry_signals'] = numpy.where(signals['fast_MA'] >
                                                signals['slow_MA'], 1.0, 0.0)
      signalinfo['exit_signals'] = numpy.where(signals['Close'] <=
                                               signals['stop'], 1.0, 0.0)
      signals['signal'][:self.long_window] = 0.0
      print signalinfo.head(50)
      print signalinfo.tail(50)
      return signals
```

This gets the code to the following:
    A    B    C
    0    1    0 (no entry signal yet, so 0)
    1    0    1 (got entry signal and haven't gotten exit signal yet, so 1)
    0    0    1 (got entry signal and haven't gotten exit signal yet, so 1)
    0    1    0 ((SHOULD BE 1) got exit signal and currently in position, so change from 1 to 0)
    0    0    0 (nothing, so stay at 0)
    1    0    1 (got entry signal and haven't gotten exit signal yet, so 1)
    0    1    0 ((SHOULD BE 1) got exit signal and currently in position, so change from 1 to 0)
    0    1    0 (got exit signal, but already at 0, so do nothing)
    1    0    1 (got entry signal and haven't gotten exit signal yet, so 1)
    0    0    1 (nothing, so stay at 0)

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I'm trying to use the ffill method as in your solution, but I'm getting a value error.

Comment: Could you post the iterative version, actually?  I originally thought I understood exactly what you wanted but then when I went to implement it realized I didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test the following code, but it can get what you want in the example, can you test it with more data?

The basic idea is fill every `1` in A and B with the index value, then we can compare which one is large, the large one is the active one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("signal.csv", delim_whitespace=True)

mask = df.copy().astype(bool)
df.A[mask.A] = df.index
df.B[mask.B] = df.index
df = df[mask].ffill()
C = df.B < df.A
C.where(C).ffill(limit=1).fillna(0)
```

output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    1
6    1
7    0
8    1
9    1
dtype: float64
```